# Does expected value of $r(\max\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_m\})$ depend on the distribution of the $X_i$?

Tags: probability

Suppose I want to take $m$ samples of real numbers wrt. some probability distrbution, call them $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_m$. Suppose it's very unlikely that the sample contains duplicates, ie. $X_i\neq X_j$ if $i\neq j$. These samples can be strictly ordered according to a rank $$r:\{X_i:i\leq m\}\to\{1,2,3,\dots,m\}$$
$$ X_i<X_j\implies r(X_i)<r(X_j) $$
Let $Y_m$ be the maximum of our samples. What is the expected value of the rank of $Y_m$? My feeling is that the expected rank of $Y_m$ is $m/2$ regardless of the probability distribution one chooses.

This can be seen clearly for $m=2$, where $P(X_1<X_2)=P(X_1>X_2)=1/2$, hence the expected rank is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$. Okay, it is not precisely $m/2$, but it is $(m+1)/2$, but this can be fixed by using indices $\{0,1,2,\dots,m-1\}$ instead.

Comment: I think your question is awkwardly phrased. I think you mean to define the rank of $Y$ as $\sum_{i = 1}^m \boldsymbol{1}_{\{Y_m = X_i\}}$. Can you edit it to make it clear for the benefit of other readers?

Comment: Also, you mean $\mathbb{P}(X_i = X_j) = 0$ whenever $i \neq j$. This is a weaker statement than $X_i \neq X_j$ whenever $i \neq j$.

Comment: while the average of $\{1,2,3,\dots,m\}$ is $\frac{m+1}{2}$, the average of $\{0,1,2,\dots,m-1\}$ is $\frac{m-1}{2}$ so this does not quite fix your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X_{1},\ldots,X_{m}$ are i.i.d., $\mathbb{P}(Y_m=X_{i})$ is a constant independent of $i$.
Since $\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=X_{j})=0$ whenever $i \neq j$, the events $\{Y_m=X_{i}\}$ partition the space and hence $\mathbb{P}(Y_m=X_{i})=1/m$.
Therefore,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^m i\boldsymbol{1}_{\{Y_m=X_{i}\}}\right]
=\sum_{i=1}^m i\mathbb{E}\left[\boldsymbol{1}_{\{Y_m=X_{i}\}}\right]
=\sum_{i=1}^{m}i\mathbb{P}(Y_m=X_{i})
=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}i
=\frac{m+1}{2},
$$
which agrees with your observations in the case of $m=2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realize $Y_m$ is necessarily one of the $X_i$. I wonder if the argument can be adapted with the idea of permutations from $S_m$ on the indices.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate.